# JS - Numbers rounded in real time

Tags: javascript, forms, real-time

I created this form to enable users to have a quote:

```
    <form name="autoSumForm">
<br><br>
Width: <input class="right" type="text" name="firstBox" value="" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
Height: <input class="right" type="text" name="secondBox" value="" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
Type: <select class="right" name="thirdBox" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();">
        <option selected="selected">-</option>
        <option value="7.80">Forex bianco 3 mm</option>
        <option value="8.30">Forex bianco 5 mm</option>
        <option value="9.90">Forex bianco 10 mm</option>
        <option value="5.70">Forex piuma 10 mm</option>
    </select><br>
Total cost: <input class="right" type="text" name="fourBox">
</form>
```

I wrote a little js to calculate total cost:

```
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
}
function calc(){
  one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value;
  three = document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value;
  document.autoSumForm.fourBox.value = (one * 1) * (two * 1) * (0.0001) * (three * 1);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
function roundNumber(number, decimals){
    var newnumber = new Number(fourBox).toFixed(parseInt(decimals));
    document.autoSumForm.fourbox.value =  parseFloat(newnumber);
}
```

Now the problem is: every time you fill the form the result is a number with many digits after comma, i tryed many things but no one went good...
Please help! Thank you!!!

PS I know that is better the server side for this type of work, but it's a simple site and every order is processed by a person.

Comment: `.value =  parseFloat(newnumber);` is going to remove the zeros added by `toFixed()` on the line above!

Comment: Why are you multiplying things by 1?

Comment: So many implicit global variables. You should really use `var` when defining them.

Comment: Why do you recalculate the total every 1ms when nothing is changing?

Comment: @Xotic750 I think theyre trying to provide real-time updates. Which should technically be done with "onkeyup" events, or something similar.

Comment: **Don't pass a string to `setInterval`.** Safe enough in this case, but you might as well get used to writing these like `setInterval(calc,50)` where you pass in the function directly. It avoids the implicit `eval`, and you should only use `eval` after you are familiar with every other tool in JavaScript and you have determined that none of them will work for you.

Comment: @Ian that is what I have assumed in my example below, I was just trying to be sure as the code is rather confused

Comment: @Xotic750 Sounds good, just thought I'd chime in with what I thought the point was :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not 100% sure about what you are trying to calculate but here are some changes that I think you may be trying to achieve, If not then it may at least set you in the right direction. BTW, it is better to use "id" rather than "name" for identifying elements as an "id" must be unique.

HTML

```
<form name="autoSumForm">
    <br>
    <br>Width:
    <input class="right" type="text" name="firstBox" value="">
    <br>Height:
    <input class="right" type="text" name="secondBox" value="">
    <br>Type:
    <select class="right" name="thirdBox">
        <option selected="selected">-</option>
        <option value="7.80">Forex bianco 3 mm</option>
        <option value="8.30">Forex bianco 5 mm</option>
        <option value="9.90">Forex bianco 10 mm</option>
        <option value="5.70">Forex piuma 10 mm</option>
    </select>
    <br>Total cost:
    <input class="right" type="text" name="fourBox" value="0.00">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var firstBox = document.querySelector("[name='firstBox']");
var secondBox = document.querySelector("[name='secondBox']");
var thirdBox = document.querySelector("[name='thirdBox']");
var fourBox = document.querySelector("[name='fourBox']");

function update() {
    fourBox.value = ((parseFloat(firstBox.value) * parseFloat(secondBox.value) * 0.0001 * parseFloat(thirdBox.value)) || 0).toFixed(2);
}

firstBox.addEventListener("keyup", update, false);
secondBox.addEventListener("keyup", update, false);
thirdBox.addEventListener("change", update, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/K8PPa/)

Wrt the comment about [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) vs [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

It is possible that the unary plus operator is faster in some case (when?), but on 2 of the most popular browsers (Chrome and firefox), [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/unary-operator-vs-parsefloat) shows that parseFloat is faster

I think parseFloat shows intent far clearer that pre-pending with "+", shorter code is not always better code

There are also differences between the two methods when converting a string, consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/DvhBQ/)

Comment: Did you know you can `parseFloat(someString)` by writing `+someString` instead? Tends to result in shorter and faster code. Some people find it easier on the eyes, although some may not.

Comment: @Cory They aren't exactly the same, but can usually be exchanged. There's reasons to use it and not to use it

Comment: Unfortunately the OP doesn't specify which behaviour is required, and as it is user input I would normally use parseFloat as it will often be used for the input verification too, the "+" operator does not fit the job quite as well here in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, it seems like something might be wrong with my local performance-testing system. Well, if it's going to be both faster and more expressive, I'd go with `parseFloat` too. And I guess if I want shorter lines, it's smarter to use line-breaks anyway.